# How can I make a map using GeoJSON data in Altair?

Tags: python, geojson, topojson, vega, altair

I'm very new to mapping, and to Altair/Vega. There's [an example in the Altair documentation for how to make a map starting with an outline of US states](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airports_count.html), which is created basically with:

```
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature='states')

# US states background
background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
)
```

but I want to plot points in the British Isles, instead. Since there are only US and World maps in the vega data collections, I would have to create my own GeoJSON, no?

So I tried getting GeoJSON for the British Isles from a world map, by running some of the command-line commands [from this blog post](https://www.vicchi.org/2013/02/27/the-great-british-map-or-great-britain-vs-the-united-kingdom-vs-the-british-isles/), namely,

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "adm0_a3 IN ('GBR','IRL','IMN','GGY','JEY','GBA')" subunits.json ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits/ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

This seems to have created a GeoJSON file, subunits.json, which probably represents the British Isles. But how can I get this into Altair? Or is there another way to make a map of the British Isles using Altair?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The example you refer to is using `topojson` structured data, while you have `geojson` structured data. So you probably need:

```py
# remote geojson data object
url_geojson = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattijn/datasets/master/two_polygons.geo.json'
data_geojson_remote = alt.Data(url=url_geojson, format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json'))

# chart object
alt.Chart(data_geojson_remote).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color="properties.name:N"
).project(
    type='identity', reflectY=True
)
```

[image: chart]

*Update*: GeoDataFrames (geopandas) are directly [supported](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#geopandas-vs-pandas) since Altair version 3.3.0. So do any objects that support the `__geo_interface__`.

---

For **more insight** read on!

Here **below** is discussed the variants:

1. Inline GeoJSON
2. Inline TopoJSON
3. TopoJSON from URL
4. GeoJSON from URL

#### Explaining the differences between `geojson` and `topojson` structured `json` files and their usage within Altair

```py
import geojson
import topojson
import pprint
import altair as alt
```

#### Inline GeoJSON

We start with creating a collection containing two features, namely two adjacent polygons.

Example of the two polygons that we will create in the GeoJSON data format.:

[image: FeatureCollection with two Features]

```py
feature_1 = geojson.Feature(
    geometry=geojson.Polygon([[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]]),
    properties={"name":"abc"}
)
feature_2 = geojson.Feature(
    geometry=geojson.Polygon([[[1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]]]),
    properties={"name":"def"}
)
var_geojson = geojson.FeatureCollection([feature_1, feature_2])
```

Inspect the created GeoJSON by pretty print the variable `var_geojson`

```py
pprint.pprint(var_geojson)
```

```
{'features': [{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[0, 0],
                                             [1, 0],
                                             [1, 1],
                                             [0, 1],
                                             [0, 0]]],
                            'type': 'Polygon'},
               'properties': {'name': 'abc'},
               'type': 'Feature'},
              {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[1, 0],
                                             [2, 0],
                                             [2, 1],
                                             [1, 1],
                                             [1, 0]]],
                            'type': 'Polygon'},
               'properties': {'name': 'def'},
               'type': 'Feature'}],
 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
```

As can be seen, the two `Polygon` `Features` are nested within the `features` object and the `geometry` is part of each `feature`.

Altair has the capability to parse nested `json` objects using the `property` key within `format`. The following is an example of such:

```py
# inline geojson data object
data_geojson = alt.InlineData(values=var_geojson, format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json')) 

# chart object
alt.Chart(data_geojson).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color="properties.name:N"
).project(
    type='identity', reflectY=True
)
```

[image: chart]

#### Inline TopoJSON

TopoJSON is an extension of GeoJSON, where the `geometry` of the `features` are referred to from a top-level object named `arcs`. This makes it possible to apply a hash function on the geometry, so each shared `arc` should only be stored once.

We can convert the `var_geojson` variable into a `topojson` file format structure:

```py
var_topojson = topojson.Topology(var_geojson, prequantize=False).to_json()
var_topojson
```

```
{'arcs': [[[1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]],
          [[1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]],
          [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]]],
 'objects': {'data': {'geometries': [{'arcs': [[-3, 0]],
                                      'properties': {'name': 'abc'},
                                      'type': 'Polygon'},
                                     {'arcs': [[1, 2]],
                                      'properties': {'name': 'def'},
                                      'type': 'Polygon'}],
                      'type': 'GeometryCollection'}},
 'type': 'Topology'}
```

Now the nested `geometry` objects are replaced by `arcs` and refer by index to the top-level `arcs` object. Instead of having a single `FeatureCollection` we now can have multiple `objects`, where our converted `FeatureCollection` is stored within the key `data` as a `GeometryCollection`.

NOTE: the key-name `data` is arbitrary and differs in each dataset.

Altair has the capability to parse the nested `data` object in the `topojson` formatted structure using the `feature` key within `format`, while declaring it is a `topojson` `type`. The following is an example of such:

```py
# inline topojson data object
data_topojson = alt.InlineData(values=var_topojson, format=alt.DataFormat(feature='data',type='topojson')) 

# chart object
alt.Chart(data_topojson).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color="properties.name:N"
).project(
    type='identity', reflectY=True
)
```

[image: chart]

#### TopoJSON from URL

There also exist a shorthand to extract the objects from a `topojson` file if this file is accessible by URL:

```py
alt.topo_feature(url, feature)
```

Altair example where a `topojson` file is referred by URL

```py
# remote topojson data object
url_topojson = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattijn/datasets/master/two_polygons.topo.json'
data_topojson_remote = alt.topo_feature(url=url_topojson, feature='data')

# chart object
alt.Chart(data_topojson_remote).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color="properties.name:N"
).project(
    type='identity', reflectY=True
)
```

[image: chart]

#### GeoJSON from URL

But for `geojson` files accessible by URL there is no such shorthand and should be linked as follows:

```py
alt.Data(url, format)
```

Altair example where a `geojson` file is referred by URL

```py
# remote geojson data object
url_geojson = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattijn/datasets/master/two_polygons.geo.json'
data_geojson_remote = alt.Data(url=url_geojson, format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json'))

# chart object
alt.Chart(data_geojson_remote).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color="properties.name:N"
).project(
    type='identity', reflectY=True
)
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `data.us_10m.url` is a string variable, where the string specifies the URL to a [geojson file](https://github.com/vega/vega-datasets/blob/master/data/us-10m.json) containing US state boundaries in the `state` feature. If you have a different geojson file you would like to use, you can substitute its URL in that example.

Comment: I keep getting a blank map when I give the URL to my file. Maybe the file I have is not a geojson file? Or maybe I'm not selecting the right feature (not sure what that is)? I'm at a total loss here.

Comment: The feature name should be one of the keys within the "objects" mapping at the top level of the JSON file.

Comment: Hm, I don't seem to have that. Maybe it's not a geojson file? It starts `{
"type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I think for geoshapes you need ``"type":"Topology"``

Comment: Your file is a `geojson` file, but the example in Altair is using `topojson`

Comment: See below answer for the differences between GeoJSON and TopoJSON formats when using in Altair, both as inline and remote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950538/2459096