# Altair choropleth -- adding values associated with each County to the map

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to add pop_april_2010 values associated with each County to the map. However my code only returns the base map when I don't include the line "color='pop_april_2010:Q'". Including the line results in an empty image without the map.

**Dataframe - df**
The data is from Kaggle > https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-feature-engineering?select=cal_populations_county.csv

[image]

**Code**

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/us-states/CA-06-california-counties.json'

source = alt.topo_feature(url, "cb_2015_california_county_20m")

alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape().encode(
tooltip='properties.NAME:N',
# color='pop_april_2010:Q'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='County',
    from_= alt.LookupData(cal2, 'County', ['pop_april_2010']),
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the chart is empty when using `color` is that the wrong column name is used in the lookup of the topojson file, so nothing is returned and you are passing a string referencing a non-existing column to `color`. If you inspect your topojson file you can see that each county's named is stored in the `NAME` attribute, not `County`.

Further, if you compare your topojson to [what is in the vega sample data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-datasets/master/data/us-10m.json) (for easier comparison [paste them into a json viewer](https://jsonviewer.com/)) you can see that the key used in the sample data file for the lookup example (`id`) is at the top level of each `geometry` object while in your fie it is nested one more level under `properties`. This means that you need to use `'properties.NAME'` as the lookup string ([more details about working geogrphical data in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950538/2166823)):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# From https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-feature-engineering?select=cal_populations_county.csv
cal2 = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/cal_populations_county.csv')

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/us-states/CA-06-california-counties.json'
source = alt.topo_feature(url, "cb_2015_california_county_20m")

alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape().encode(
    tooltip='properties.NAME:N',
    color='pop_april_2010:Q'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='properties.NAME',
    from_= alt.LookupData(cal2, 'County', ['pop_april_2010']),
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
)
```

[image]