# Problem while displaying Choropleth map for UK using Altair

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair, choropleth

I am downloading dataset from two different sources for UK areas. And I am using Altair code to display a Choropleth Map. But this what I get for both datasets using the following code:

```
_map = alt.Chart(geo_uk, title='UK Map').mark_geoshape().encode().properties(width=500,height=300);
```

[Link to used data source (GeoJson file)](https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b7fc294e5c8643f5b506acc2122c6880_0.geojson)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't use altair all the time, so I don't know if my answer is satisfactory to you. I created a map with the information available from the given geojson file. My answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923300/how-can-i-make-a-map-using-geojson-data-in-altair/55950538#55950538). If the map is not the one you intend, you may need to convert it in the world geodetic system.

```
import altair as alt
import json

file = './data/Local_Authority_Districts__April_2019__UK_BGC_v2.geojson'
with open(file) as f:
    data_json = json.load(f) 

geo_uk = alt.Data(values=data_json, format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json'))

_map = alt.Chart(geo_uk, title='UK Map').mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    color="properties.LAD19NM:N"
).project(
    type='identity', reflectY=True
).properties(width=800,height=600)
_map
```

[image]